# onmouseover event javascript links

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, mouseover

I am trying to have an event occur anytime you hover over any link from a webpage.

I think I need to use the mouseover event but I dont know how I can to do this.

I just want it to recognize it, and give me an alert. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
    function(el) {
        console.log(el);
        el.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
          alert(el);
        });
    });
```

if you can use jQuery, it's even easier:

```
$('a').on("mouseover", function(e) {
  alert(e.target);
});
```